# adding item to an array

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

How do I add an item to a multidimensional array? I want to add the price to item2 but I get "push is not a function"

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

        [Bindable]
        public var dp:Array = [ 
            { label: "item1", desc: "this is item 1"  },
            { label: "item2", desc: "this is item 2"  },
            { label: "item3", desc: "this is item 3"  }
        ];


        private function addItem():void{
            var v:String = '$8.99';
            dp[1].push( ("price:", v ) ); 
            dp.refresh();

        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>


<mx:VBox> 
    <mx:Repeater id="r" dataProvider="{myAC}">
        <mx:RadioButton label="{r.currentItem.label}"/>
        <mx:Text text="{r.currentItem.desc}"/>
        <mx:Text text="{r.currentItem.price}"/>
    </mx:Repeater>


<s:Button label="push" click="addItem()"/>


</mx:VBox> 


</mx:Application>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an array of objects, not an array of arrays.  Try this:

```
    [Bindable]
    public var dp:Array = [ 
        { label: "item1", desc: "this is item 1", price : ""  },
        { label: "item2", desc: "this is item 2", price : ""  },
        { label: "item3", desc: "this is item 3", price : ""  }
    ];

    private function addItem():void{
        var v:String = '$8.99';
        dp[1]["price"] = v; 
        dp.refresh();

    }
```

Comment: use ArrayCollection instead of Array:  public var dp:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([ 
        { label: "item1", desc: "this is item 1", price : ""  },
        { label: "item2", desc: "this is item 2", price : ""  },
        { label: "item3", desc: "this is item 3", price : ""  }
    ]);

see: http://blog.flexdevelopers.com/2009/03/flex-basics-arraycollection.html